# Автоматическая отправка сообщений PyTelegramAPI после обновления FireBase

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-database

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы после новой записи в Cloud Firestore Телеграм бот отправлял сообщение с этой самой записью.

Я пытался вызвать 'bot.send_message' внутри этой функции, когда слушал изменения в БД, но это не работает. В консоли все работает.

PyTelegramAPI

```
def on_snapshot(doc_snapshot, changes, read_time):
   recent = []
   for doc in doc_snapshot:
       data = f'{"Имя: ", doc.get("name")}'
       recent.append(data)
   print('\n'.join(recent))
   recent.clear()
   callback_done.set()
doc_watch = items_ref.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел ответ. Необходимо воспользоваться `bot.send_message`, предварительно получив id вашего чата. Для этого вам надо в любой функции с аргументом `message` получить id вот так:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
# получаем id
    print(message.chat.id)
```

После того как id появился в консоли, копируем его. Теперь мы можем его использовать.
Слушаем изменения БД (FireBase)

```
def on_snapshot(doc_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    bot.send_message(your_id,'database has been changed')
```

Подробнее о отслеживании изменений в реальном времени: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen?authuser=0